# Wrong Character Set for JSF's h:inputText on first submit (only)

Tags: jsf

In the following form, we try to return a user's input to JSF's `h:inputText` or PrimeFaces' `p:inputText`. 
We experience strange behavior when non-Latin characters (Japanese, Hebrew, etc. ) are entered:

On first request we get unrecognized character set, but on the second request - we get a correct result.

**Input/Output Examples (first run only):**

1. *Japanese*: 
    input = 日
    output = æ¥
2. *Hebrew*:
    input = א
    output = ×

**JSF:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
    <body>
        <h:form>   
            <h:outputLabel value="Name:"/>                        
            <h:inputText value="#{newTestController.registeredCustomerFirstName}"/>
            <h:commandButton value="Continue" action="#{newTestController.RegisteredNewCustomer(actionEvent)}"/>
        </h:form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

**Backing Bean:**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "newTestController")
@SessionScoped
public class NewTestController {

    private String registeredCustomerFirstName;

    public String getRegisteredCustomerFirstName() {
        return registeredCustomerFirstName;
    }

    public void setRegisteredCustomerFirstName(String registeredCustomerFirstName) {
        this.registeredCustomerFirstName = registeredCustomerFirstName;
    }

    public void RegisteredNewCustomer(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

Comment: `h:inputText` is from standard JSF. Don't you mean `p:inputText`? As to the problem, how and where exactly did you confirm that the characters are mojibake? While printing to logs and reading it? Or when checking the redisplayed form after submit?

Comment: Sorry. This happens both on `p:inputText` and `h:input`, so it's probably relevant to JSF, not primefaces. As to the problem: It is visible upon re-displaying, logging and a breakpoint set on `getRegisteredCustomerFirstName()`.

Comment: I have a solution without an explanation. For glassfish add:<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" /> to glassfish-web.xml. Still - why is it failing on the first time only?

Comment: @Daniel What is the solution for tomcat, any idea?

Comment: @Koray Tugay Maybe. Have you tried:http://balusc.blogspot.co.il/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html ? Clause 3 includes some notes about tomcat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented above - it is needed to define a default-charset for the application server.

For glassfish: add `<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" />` to `glassfish-web.xml`.

For other application servers see BalusC's [blog](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to < http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18007 >.  That fix was made to prevent a warning message when we unconditionally set the encoding to UTF-8, which would seem to be what we want, but in this case we felt it safer to not do it.

I've created a related issue in Mojarra, < http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2217 >.  Bottom line: setting the encoding explicitly in the app configuration is the right solution.  The implementation is already doing the right thing.

Comment: Hello, I am using Tomcat however I have the exact same problem.

Comment: Did setting the configuration in the app as explained in issue 2217 not resolve the problem there?

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544262/jsf-utf-8-characters-not-seen-only-in-first-form-post-jsf-tomcat @edburns thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying charset in the config file might be not enough.
Try using p:commandButton instead of h:commandButton. The p:commandButton by default uses ajax, while the h:commandButton does non-ajax submit.