# JSF UTF 8 characters not seen ONLY in first form post, jsf, tomcat?

Tags: jsf, tomcat, utf-8

I have a simple JSF form where I submit a username and password and persist to database.

Only in first form submit, I am having problems with UTF-8 characters. When I submit **ğğüüçç** in first post, I get wrong characters. In the second try, it is alright.

Here is my web.xml and index.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

and my index.xhtml :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div class="container">
        <h:form styleClass="form-signin" prependId="false" id="registirationForm">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please Register!</h2>
            <h:inputText styleClass="input-block-level" value="#{registirationFormBean.nickname}" />
            <h:inputSecret styleClass="input-block-level" value="#{registirationFormBean.password}"/>
            <h:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-large btn-primary" value="Register Me!" action="#{registirationFormBean.registerUser}"/>
        </h:form>
    </div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**Edit: This is from server.xml in Tomcat**

```
 <Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
               maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
               enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
               connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
   />
```

When I debug my application, in the first post I see values posted:

[image]

But in the second time:

[image]

Comment: Does adding `<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>`    to your in your html and `accept-charset="utf-8"` to `h:form` make any difference?

Comment: @dratewka Hello, no it did not make any difference.

Comment: @BalusC - actually IE is the main reason why I suggested this. We had a somwhat similar issue in one of our projects (only under IE) and modifying the form solved it. Still thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use

```
<f:view>
```

and your locale.

```
    <f:view locale="#{registirationFormBean.locale}" encoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html"> 
<h:head>
    <title>Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div class="container">
        <h:form styleClass="form-signin" prependId="false" id="registirationForm">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please Register!</h2>
            <h:inputText styleClass="input-block-level" value="#{registirationFormBean.nickname}" />
            <h:inputSecret styleClass="input-block-level" value="#{registirationFormBean.password}"/>
            <h:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-large btn-primary" value="Register Me!" action="#{registirationFormBean.registerUser}"/>
        </h:form>
    </div>
</h:body>

</f:view>
```

provide locale object from your bean like .

```
public Locale getLocale(){
return new Locale("tr", "TR");
}
```