# JSF input field shows mojibake only on first request after deployment, then it works fine

Tags: jsf, character-encoding, facelets, mojibake

I wrote a parser, which can parse Hiragana text to Romaji text.
Then I made a facelet which you can see on Picture1. If I enter any Hiragana text and I click the translate button, it shows garbage text in both textareas. The parser library has unit tests, and all tests are passed.
I also made a small JavaFX GUI using the same lib, and the bug is not present there. This bug only presents after I deploy it and run it in a browser. I'm using JSF 2.2 and Glassfish 4.1.0 as container.

---

Picture1:
[image: Image1]
When I re-enter the same text after this garbage was shown, it works well.
It works as it supposed to any other time.
You can see it on Picture2. I enter the very same text and it works well after the initial bug.

---

Picture2:
[image: Image2]

---

Here is the code of the index.xhtml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Convert Hiragana, Romaji</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"/>
        <f:view>
            <div class="H_OuterDiv">
                <h1><h:outputText value="Hiragana to Romaji" /></h1>
                <h:form>
                    <div class="H_HiraganaTextArea">
                        <h3><h:outputText value="Enter Hiragana" /></h3>
                        <h:inputTextarea cols="30" rows="20" value="#        {hconverter.hiraganaInput}"></h:inputTextarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="H_MiddleDiv">
                        <div class="H_ButtonsDiv">
                            <h:commandButton value="Translate" action="#    {hconverter.convertHiraganaToRomaji()}"></h:commandButton>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </h:form>
                <div class="H_RomajiTextArea">
                    <h3>
                        Enter Romaji Text
                    </h3>
                    <h:inputTextarea value="#{hconverter.romajiOutput}"     cols="30" rows="20" />
                </div>
            </div>
    </f:view>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

---

And here is the code of the managed bean. The HiraganaLettersNew class is a singleton.

```
@RequestScoped
@Named
public class Hconverter {
    private String hiraganaInput = null;
    private String romajiOutput = null;

    public String getHiraganaInput() {
        return hiraganaInput;
    }

    public void setHiraganaInput(String hiraganaInput) {
        this.hiraganaInput = hiraganaInput;
    }

    public String getRomajiOutput() {
        return romajiOutput;
    }

    public void setRomajiOutput(String romajiOutput) {
        this.romajiOutput = romajiOutput;
    }

    public void convertHiraganaToRomaji()   {
        HiraganaLettersNew parser = HiraganaLettersNew.getInstance();
        romajiOutput = parser.parseHiraganaString(hiraganaInput);
    }
}
```

---

Could somebody please help me? I'm new to facelets and JavaEE, and I don't have any ideas why is this bug happening. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrong Character Set for JSF's h:inputText on first submit (only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647380/wrong-character-set-for-jsfs-hinputtext-on-first-submit-only)

Answer (score 0):

**I found a solution.**

This solution works with glassfish.
I had to create a file glassfish-web.xml in this structure. Take note it's a maven project.

```
{projectRoot}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml
```

---

The file contains this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD 
GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" 
"http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <locale-charset-info>
        <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" />
    </locale-charset-info>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

After a clean deploy, the bug is gone.
This question is a duplicate, I didn't know it when I asked.

---

See also:
[It has been asked here before.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647380/wrong-character-set-for-jsfs-hinputtext-on-first-submit-only)

[BalusC's blog](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)